# Class activation map to weakly supervised semantic segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I have a classifier model using the fine-tuning technique and training it with a dataset for the classification of tree species, achieving a 98% F1 score from sklearn in training like this image. [image: F1 metric] I'm using the "grad-cam" module to generate my own CAMs for weakly supervised semantic segmentation. I have an image like this:
[image]

and the model's output applying the sigmoid function indicates that there is only one class in this image like this(Only class 14º in the picture):
[image]
However, when I use the module's function to generate CAMs for different classes, it can be observed that there are some parts in red as well. Why is this?
(example about CAM on the 0º class[incorrect class in image]):
[image]
If the model already correctly predicts that there is only one class, why is there another class in red?
(example about CAM on the 14º class[correct class in image]):
[image]
It's as if the model is saying this part of the image belongs to that class. How can I generate the pseudo-mask for such an image if there is a "conflict" in the CAM?
I am using the example code from "https://jacobgil.github.io/pytorch-gradcam-book/introduction.html", but with my model